# Cannot move out of an `Arc`

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have a struct called routing with the following methods.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Routing {
    get_routes: Node<PyFunction>,
    post_routes: Node<PyFunction>,
    put_routes: Node<PyFunction>,
    delete_routes: Node<PyFunction>,
    patch_routes: Node<PyFunction>,
    head_routes: Node<PyFunction>,
    options_routes: Node<PyFunction>,
    connect_routes: Node<PyFunction>,
    trace_routes: Node<PyFunction>,
}

impl Routing {
    pub fn new(router: &Router) -> Routing {
        let get_routes = Router::protocol_to_tree(&router.get_routes);
        let post_routes = Router::protocol_to_tree(&router.post_routes);
        let put_routes = Router::protocol_to_tree(&router.put_routes);
        let delete_routes = Router::protocol_to_tree(&router.delete_routes);
        let patch_routes = Router::protocol_to_tree(&router.patch_routes);
        let head_routes = Router::protocol_to_tree(&router.head_routes);
        let options_routes = Router::protocol_to_tree(&router.options_routes);
        let connect_routes = Router::protocol_to_tree(&router.connect_routes);
        let trace_routes = Router::protocol_to_tree(&router.trace_routes);

        Self {
            get_routes,
            post_routes,
            put_routes,
            delete_routes,
            patch_routes,
            head_routes,
            options_routes,
            connect_routes,
            trace_routes,
        }
    }

    #[inline(always)]
    fn get_relevant_map(self, route: &Method) -> Option<Node<PyFunction>> {
        match route {
            &Method::GET => Some(self.get_routes),
            &Method::POST => Some(self.post_routes),
            &Method::PUT => Some(self.put_routes),
            &Method::PATCH => Some(self.patch_routes),
            &Method::DELETE => Some(self.delete_routes),
            &Method::HEAD => Some(self.head_routes),
            &Method::OPTIONS => Some(self.options_routes),
            &Method::CONNECT => Some(self.connect_routes),
            &Method::TRACE => Some(self.trace_routes),
            _ => None,
        }
    }

    #[inline(always)]
    pub fn get_route(self, route_method: &Method, route: &str) -> Option<PyFunction> {
        println!("Hello world how are your");
        let table = self.get_relevant_map(route_method)?;

        let x = match table.at(route) {
            Ok(res) => Some(res.value.clone()),
            Err(_) => None,
        };

        x
    }
}
```

and I am trying to access call the `get_route` method of the implementation, but I am getting an error.

```rust
async fn index(
    router: web::Data<Arc<Routing>>,
    headers: web::Data<Arc<Headers>>,
    mut payload: web::Payload,
    req: HttpRequest,
) -> impl Responder {
    let x = match (&router)
        .clone()
        .get_route(&req.method().clone(), req.uri().path())
        .clone()
    {
        Some(handler_function) => {
            return handle_request(&handler_function, &headers, &mut payload, &req).await
        }
        None => {
            let mut response = HttpResponse::Ok();
            apply_headers(&mut response, &headers);
            return response.finish();
        }
    };

    x
}
```

```sh
[rustc E0507] [E] cannot move out of an `Arc`

move occurs because value has type `router::Routing`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Complete error message:

```sh
error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Arc`
   --> src/server.rs:160:19
    |
160 |       let x = match (&router)
    |  ___________________^
161 | |         .clone()
    | |________________^ move occurs because value has type `Routing`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 2 warnings emitted

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0308, E0507.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `robyn`
```

I have tried wrapping the properties of the struct in Arc, Locks but still am unable to figure out the solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: `get_route()` and `get_relevant_map()` should take `&self`, not `self`. Taking self means that they take ownership of the object when called, rendering it unusable for the caller. This is not needed for these functions, and is incompatible with the object being behind a reference (which is what happens when it's "inside" an `Arc`.)

Comment: @Aiden4 , I have added the error message.

Comment: @user4815162342 , I don't think I get your point. Would passing a referenced object in an Arc makes it cloneable?

Comment: @SanskarJethi `Arc` makes every object clonable by cloning the reference-counted pointer. The problem with your code (and, I suspect, the reason why you introduced all those calls to clone), is that methods like `get_route()` and `get_relevant_map()` take `self` instead of `&self`. That is unnecessary and wrong, so you should change it first.